# transform multi multi line to multi on line file

Tags: text-processing, csv

This is the file i want to transform:

```
john doe  
555-666-333  
john@gmail.com  
die  
jane doe  
Beverly Hills
444-333-111  
jane@gmail.com  
die
```

I want to result file to be like that:

```
john doe,555-666-333,john@gmail.com  
jane doe,Beverly Hills,444-333-111,jane@gmail.com
```

The word `die` is in the file and i want to use it to delimit my lines, that's way they will don't appear in the output as show above.

**edit**
I have change the format of the file. The former format doesn't take in account the fact that number of words between `die` can vary.

Comment: By `dot`, do you mean `die`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '/^die$/ { print substr(lines,2); lines=""; next } { lines=lines OFS $0 }' file
john doe,555-666-333,john@gmail.com
jane doe,Beverly Hills,444-333-111,jane@gmail.com
```

Same thing here applies regarding data that contains commas (see end of my answer below). If the data contains commas, you may want to use this:

```
awk -v OFS=',' '
    /^die$/ { print substr(lines,2); lines=""; next }
    /,/     { $0=sprintf("\"%s\"", $0 ) }
            { lines=lines OFS $0 }' file
```

The code builds up a string in `lines` that is delimited by `OFS` (a comma). When the word `die` is found by itself on a line, the string in `lines` is outputted.  Tho `substr()` call removes the comma that was added in front of the line when the first field of the record was appended to the string.  Lines with commas are handled the same way as in my code below.

Using GNU `awk` or `mawk`, but not BSD `awk`, you could also do

```
mawk -v RS='\ndie\n' -v FS='\n' -v ORS='\n' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1;print}' file
```

This would not produce quoted fields for data that contains commas.

The `$1=$1` forces `awk` to re-form the record according to the `OFS` (output field separator) and `ORS` (output record separator) variables before outputting.

---

Answer before update to question:

```
paste -d, - - - - <file
```

This would produce

```
john doe,555-666-333,john@gmail.com,die
jane doe,444-333-111,jane@gmail.com,die
```

To remove the `die` lines (these are totally unnecessary):

```
paste -d, - - - - <file | cut -d, -f 1-3
```

The above works if the original data contains no commas.

You can also filter out the `die` lines from the start:

```
sed '/^die$/d' file | paste -d, - - -
```

This would work even if the original data contains commas.

If the data contains commas, you may want to preprocess it to add quotes around those lines:

```
awk '/^die$/ { next } /,/ { $0=sprintf("\"%s\"", $0 ) } 1' file | paste -d, - - -
```

Given the file

```
john doe
555-666-333
john@gmail.com
die
jane doe
444-333-111
jane@gmail.com
die
Me, myself and I
000-000-000
myself@example.com
```

that last command would generate

```
john doe,555-666-333,john@gmail.com
jane doe,444-333-111,jane@gmail.com
"Me, myself and I",000-000-000,myself@example.com
```

Comment: Running your code above i obtain:    `john doe,555-666-333,john@gmail.com,janedoe,444-333-111`   `444-333-111,jane@gmail.com,"Me, myself and I",000-000-000,`   `myself@example.com`

Comment: The lines are not clearly separeted.

Comment: @AnicetEbou If the records contain different number of fields, how can you later distinguish what's what? See also updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a kind of idiomatic `awk` like this:

```
$ awk '$1=$1' RS='.die\n' OFS="," FS='\n' file1
john doe,555-666-333,john@gmail.com
jane doe,Beverly Hills,444-333-111,jane@gmail.com
```

In above `awk`, we define Record Separator `RS` to be the `die` entry that is used in your file to separate person's details.

`$1=$1` forces awk to recalculate and print input fields using "," as Output Field Separator `OFS`

PS: When i'am suspicious of bad file endings like `\r` i use to call `tr` to remove possible `\r` characters: `tr -d '\r' file1 |awk .....`

By the way, you use also sed like this:

```
$ sed -z 's/\n/,/g; s/,die,/\n/g'
```

This will produce the same output as awk, by fooling sed to use null character as record separator.

As soon as there are not real null chars in the input file, sed will treat the whole input file as a big record == a big line.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the "sed" editor in a POSIX manner

```
sed -e '
    :a
       $q;N;y/\n/,/
       s/,die$//;t
    ba
' input_file
```

Method:

- Setup a loop and append the next line into the pattern space.

  - **N** command
- Change the newline to comma and then try to strip off the ",die"

  - **y///** **s///** commands
- In case you succeed, then you"re all set and do no further processing for this.

  - **t** command without a label
- Otherwise, go back for more and just in case we are eof, we bail out.

  - **b**   and    **q**   commands.

We could also use Perl for this:

```
perl -lne '
    push @A, $_ unless /^die$/;
    print join ",", splice @A if /^die$/ || eof;
' input_file
```

Where we accumulate lines in an array until we see the "die" line. At which point we join the array contents by means of comma (also empty out the array).

We could also slurp the file and then invoke Perl to get the results:

```
perl -lF'/^die\n/m' -0777nae 'print join ",", split /\n/ for @F' input_file
```

- **-F**'/^die\n/m' will split the file slurped as a string on the regex BOL die followed by a newline.
- **-0**777 will turn on slurping. **-n** shall disable autoprint of lines and **-a** will split the slurped lines (in our case just one line) based on the **-F** value.